# Galaxy S IV does not have voice recognizer intent?

Tags: android, android-4.2-jelly-bean, voice-recognition

I created an app that uses voice recognition and it works on most phones however on the new galaxy S IV and Galaxy note II it fails with:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{<my.pakage.myactivity>/<my.pakage.myactivity>}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH (has extras) }
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2247)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2297)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:152)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1282)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5328)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.speech.action.RECOGNIZE_SPEECH (has extras) }
at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1659)
at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1434)
at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3430)
at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.superStartActivity(_HoloActivity.java:717)
at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.startActivityForResult(_HoloActivity.java:698)
at android.support.v4.app._HoloActivity.startActivityForResult(_HoloActivity.java:689)
at com.ltandfumbles.soundoff.activites.Record.speak(Record.java:263)
at com.ltandfumbles.soundoff.activites.Record.onCreate(Record.java:96)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5250)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
... 11 more
```

The code that triggers this is:

```
 void speak() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);

        //intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, metTextHint.getText().toString());

        // Given an hint to the recognizer about what the user is going to say
        //There are two form of language model available
        //1.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH : For short phrases
        //2.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM : If not sure about the words or phrases and its domain.
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
                RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH);

        int noOfMatches = 3;
        // Specify how many results you want to receive. The results will be
        // sorted where the first result is the one with higher confidence.
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_MAX_RESULTS, noOfMatches);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Speak now");
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 2000);
        intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, 2000);

        //Start the Voice recognizer activity for the result.
        startActivityForResult(intent, VOICE_RECOGNITION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
```

I realize that error is a result of no suitable application on the device but I find it hard to believe that the new devices don't have any voice recognition capabilities. Is there some change in android 4.2.2 that I need to account for?

Comment: Have you gone into settings and made sure a voice provider is set?  It should be under languages and input, there's a section for voice.  Its on the Samsung Note 2, so it ought to be on the S4.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have Google Voice Search installed/enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the exception.

There is no guarantee that an Intent will get a match, and the
situation can change as the user adds and deletes applications.
Conceivably, matches could go away in future version of Android, or in
a port of Android with very different hardware than a phone. So even
if it works in many Android configurations, this is still an exception
you should handle.

You may check that action before calling:

```
    // Check to see if a recognition activity is present
    PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
            new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH),0);
    if (activities.size() == 0) {
          // At this point there is no recognition library and you
          // should handle it here

    }
```